# Pivot_table Top 5 How?

Tags: python, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a top 5 with a few columns so I tried this:

```
items_top_5 = df_train.sort_values (by = "item", ascending = False) .head (5)

sales_top_5 = df_train.sort_values (by = "sales", ascending = False) .head (5)
```

And then I want to play these two variables inside the pivot table, more or less like this:

```
itens_sales_pivot_top_5 = pd.pivot_table (df_train, index = ["store"], values = ["sales"], columns = ["itens_top_5"],
                                    aggfunc = [np.sum]). head (5)

print (itens_sales_pivot_top_5)
```

But the code above doesn't work and I don't know why. And I would like to create a graph using the pivot table.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Also did you copy-paste your code into the post, or did you manually retype? There are some typos like `itens` vs `items`, but I'm not sure that's in the original code.

Comment: briefly this is: KeyError: 'itens_top_5'

Any tips on how to make this work? (using the pivot table)

Comment: It's all the same, I don't know how to use pivot_table to make the top 5.

Comment: Then it seems that's really a typo in your code. You originally define it as `items_top_5` and later use `columns=["itens_top_5"]` (m vs n).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what is the right format to put inside columns?

Comment: I'm using this dataset: https: //www.kaggle.com/c/demand-forecasting-kernels-only

But it is not right.

Comment: I don't know how you can be confused.  You have made a typographical error.  You are looking for `itens_top_5`.  It's not "itens".  It's "items". Spelling matters.

Comment: Okay, I solved it, but it doesn't work. Nothing appears in the table.

Comment: This dataset is not very easy, practically everything worked, but what I want is to make a top 5 of the values and visualize them in tables and then in graphs.